# Eclipse JEE: Can I safely exclude .cfs and .index files when backing up?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was disappointed that my Eclipse JEE projects were so huge because it made them a little hard to sync with my friend's system. 
Then I finally had a look and see 
org.eclipse.m2e.core Nexus plugin files (.cfs) AND 
eclipse indexes (.index) 
are using up 96% of the directory sizes!!

Is it safe to exclude *.cfs and *.index? Will this corrupt my projects?

Answer (score 0):

Nexus is used by maven Eclipse plugin to create indexes so you can search by artifactID, groupID and classname.

> Nexus is a Maven Repository manager from Sonatype which is available for download at http://nexus.sonatype.org. Nexus maintains an index of all artifacts and metadata in the Maven Central Repository which allows tools like Nexus and m2eclipse to rapidly search the contents of a Maven repository. 
>   https://www.theserverside.com/news/1363817/Introduction-to-m2eclipse

It's just an index so you can definitely exclude .index and .cfs files in any nexus/*/   from your backup.